# Connecting to MongoDB with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

My XML file looks like this

```
<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}"/>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="SmartSearch" mongo-ref="mongo" username="${mongo.user}" password="${mongo.password}"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>

<mongo:repositories base-package="be.omniatravel.service.repository"/>
```

I have the latest dependency for MongoDB in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It connects properly on the startup of my Tomcat server, but when i try to interact with the db i get the following error

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [MY_DATABASE], username = [MY_USERNAME], password = [MY_PASSWORD]

I made sure the db, user and password are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in my question was correct.

The problem was that the server admin changed the database name from SmartSearch to SmartSearchDev.